# Why is `parseInt` behaving differently and returning only 23 for numbers greater than 23?

Tags: javascript, parseint

Why is `parseInt()` returning 23 for values / numbers greater than 23? Seeing this strange behaviour and not sure why is this happening? Can someone help me explain why?

```js
console.log(parseInt(null, 10));
console.log(parseInt(null, 23));
console.log(parseInt(null, 24));
console.log(parseInt(null, 30));
```

Comment: You know you are setting the 'radix' of the function parseInt, right? See https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Yes, I know first argument is number, but this is something that just got discovered while working on something and was wondering why is it happening?

Comment: it changes after base 30 (on mozilla). check different browsers' js engine source code, how and why they've implemented such way -))

Comment: this is the  same as `parseInt('n', 23)`, see duplicate